# Python 3.* Changing window background via button click

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been using the site for a while, very helpful for many things linux and python, so thanks :) I have found out how to put a background on an application window. I made a button that leads to a function that does basically the same thing I did to set the background originally. I have tried several different ways and google searched this. The only thing I've managed is to either blank the screen completely, or keep the button but still blank the background.

Here is the code I'm working on currently

```
import tkinter

from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter

window = tkinter.Tk()

myImage2 = Image.open("cubecap.png")
myImage1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(myImage2)

bglabel = tkinter.Label(window, image=myImage1)
bglabel.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

btn = tkinter.Button(window, font=('Monospace', 16), text="Click it!")
btn.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def changeBackground():
    myNewImage2 = Image.open("cubecap2.png")
    myNewImage1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(myNewImage2)

    bglabel.configure(image=myNewImage1)

    btn.configure(text="!it Click")

btn.configure(command=changeBackground)

window.title("Background Changing Buttons")

window.geometry('600x480')

window.wm_iconbitmap('@matrix.xbm')

window.mainloop()
```

I've tried re'.place'ing the label as well, but it still just blanks the screen. I'm very new to python, and only a hobby programmer.

EDIT:
I solved this by setting the other image varaibles outside the changeBackground function

Comment: The reason is because the images would be getting garbage collected once the function completes, the othe way to fix it woukd be to make your image global

Answer (score 0):

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageFilter

window = Tkinter.Tk()

myImage2 = Image.open("'/home/user/logo.png'")
myImage1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(myImage2)

bglabel = Tkinter.Label(window, image=myImage1)
bglabel.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)


def changeBackground():
    global btn,myNewImage1,bglabel 

    bglabel.config(image=myNewImage1)


myNewImage2 = Image.open("/home/venkat/Peer/logo.ico")

myNewImage1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(myNewImage2)

btn = Tkinter.Button(window, font=('Monospace', 16), text="Click it!",command=changeBackground)

btn.pack(side=BOTTOM)

window.title("Background Changing Buttons")

window.geometry('600x480')

window.mainloop()
```